# How to exclude specific files with the tar command?

Tags: linux, tar

Let's assume I have the following directory structure

```
dir/
├── subdir
│   ├── dir
│   │   └── TODO.txt
│   └── TODO.txt
└── TODO.txt
```

I wish to bundle `dir/` recursively into a tarball with the command `tar` on Linux, but *I want to exclude the root TODO.txt*. How can I specify this with a relative path ?

**Attempt #1**

```
tar -czf dir.tar.gz  dir/ --exclude='TODO.txt'
```

Doesn't work : it gets rid of *every* TODO.txt in the resulting tarball :

```
dir/
└── subdir
    └── dir
```

**Attempt #2**

```
tar -czf dir.tar.gz  dir/ --exclude='dir/TODO.txt'
```

This also fails, because the `dir` subdirectory is also matched by this pattern. The resulting tarball hence contains

```
dir/
└── subdir
    ├── dir
    └── TODO.txt
```

Is there any way I can specify exactly that I want to exclude the root TODO.txt with a relative path ?

Comment: Can't you simply move that single file aside whilst creating the archive?

Comment: Otherwise you can feed that `tar` command with the output of a `find` which you filter by a `grep -v` which allows to anchor the pattern to the start of the hit.

Comment: Wrong site, not a programming question.

Comment: @tink I don't think so. Just look at all the similar questions related to the `tar` tag.
@arkascha Thanks, this line does the job : `find ./dir/ | grep -v "\./dir/TODO.txt"`. Feeding the output to the `tar` command gives me strange results, however. I keep digging.

Comment: @Backslash36 : just because something happens repeatedly doesn't make it right?

Comment: @tink of course not, yet there is a tag dedicated to the topic. To me, your statement is an opinion, not a fact.

Comment: @Backslash36 Of course you're entitled to that view; but you're wrong :D  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic   Granted, I'm sure there are programmers who use tar, that doesn't make tar a "programmers tool". OK, there's a Linux tag, but that's to help people focus on Linux programming questions (e.g., a .Net developer may not jump on a question about X11 windowing).

Comment: @tink I don't really get your fury about all this, but I'll leave it there :)

Comment: No fury @Backslash36 :} ... just the desire to keep things tidy. Your topic has two close votes so far, and I'll leave it at that ;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @arkascha 's answer :

```
find dir/ -type f | grep -v "^dir/TODO.txt" > files.txt
```

then

```
tar -czf dir.tar.gz -T files.txt
```

From the first line, there are 2 tricks to pay attention to :

1. **The `-type f` option**. If not put, directories will be included in `find`'s result. This is bad, because it would include each file as many times as their depth in the file hierarchy.
2. The `^` in `grep`'s regex : it ensures that we're excluding the pattern from the begining of the file hierarchy

Comment: Using the `-T` option (`--files-from`) any filenames starting with a hyphen will be *treated as command line options*. To suppress this behaviour use `--verbatim-files-from` instead: [https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `dir/` to name your transfer, cd into `dir`, then name it as `.`. The folder name `.` will never appear later in any files path, so it serves as a robust anchor. Then use `--transform=`, to have the paths in the archive begin with `dir/`.

**Demonstration**

without filter:

```
$ tar -czf dir.tar.gz -v dir
dir/
dir/TODO.txt
dir/subdir/
dir/subdir/TODO.txt
dir/subdir/dir/
dir/subdir/dir/TODO.txt
```

cd into `dir`, name it as `.`:

```
$ tar -czf dir.tar.gz -v -C dir .
./
./TODO.txt
./subdir/
./subdir/TODO.txt
./subdir/dir/
./subdir/dir/TODO.txt
```

exclude, anchoring on `.`:

```
$ tar -czf dir.tar.gz -v -C dir --exclude='./TODO.txt' .
./
./subdir/
./subdir/TODO.txt
./subdir/dir/
./subdir/dir/TODO.txt
```

change `.` back to `dir` inside the archive (--show-transformed-names makes `tar` show the names as they go into the archive):

```
$ tar -czf dir.tar.gz -v -C dir --exclude='./TODO.txt' --transform='s/^\./dir/g' --show-transformed-names .
dir/
dir/subdir/
dir/subdir/TODO.txt
dir/subdir/dir/
dir/subdir/dir/TODO.txt
```